# How to build desktop project and get .exe for all operation systems?

Tags: linux, windows, flutter, macos, desktop-application

I have a problem: I need to get 'Release' folder of my application for MacOS and Linux, but my OS is Windows. For Windows I've already build project and [here is generated 'Release' folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBdz8.png). I need the same for MacOS and Linux, but I don't know how to do it using my current Windows OS. However I got it for the Linux through the VM with Ubuntu, but it's very boring and I haven't even a VM for MacOS, so I'm searching for any other solutions except of getting MacOS Release on MacOS, Ubuntu on Ubuntu etc.

I've tried to write `flutter build macos` and `flutter build linux` in console and expect to get 'Release' folder for MacOS and for Linux but I got [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buUdw.png).

Comment: if you want to build for macos, you need to build your app in macos environment. https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/macos

Comment: To add to that, you can build all platforms with something like github actions.  It won't be free.